# A web browser (or plugin) without any reserved shortcuts or hotkeys

Tags: web-browser

In remote management web apps (web VNC clients, web shells, etc) you should be able to use all keys in your keyboard, including usual browser hotkeys like Ctrl+W, Ctrl+N, Ctrl+T, sometimes even some global hotkeys like Alt+F4...

I'm looking a for solution that allows me open these web apps and is able to  send these keys to the webapp instead of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Vivaldi has customizable hotkeys and you can remove all of them for your purpose.